# Can we store date on eosio table?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, table, eosio-cpp

Is there any direct datatype in eosio to store date? and if not then how can we store dates in  eosio table?

void mainloan::paymentConfirm(uint64_t pay_id,**uint64_t pay_date**,double pay_amunt,name from ,uint64_t loan_id){
require_auth(_self);

payMade_table.emplace(get_self(),[&](auto &p){
    p.pay_id=payMade_table.available_primary_key();
    p.pay_date=pay_date;
    p.pay_amunt=pay_amunt;
    p.pay_from=from;
    p.loan_id=loan_id;
});

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can either convert the data to a `uint64_t` as you have showed above, or you can use the time_point types:

```
time_point
time_point_sec
block_timestamp_type
```

I believe of the above, `time_point_sec` is likely most common. `time_point_sec` is a lower resolution timestamp accurate to seconds.

`time_point_sec` format:

`yyyy-MM-dd T HH:mm:ssz`

`time_point` format:

`yyyy-MM-dd T HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSz`

[List of Available EOS Datatypes](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/list-of-available-datatypes-for-action-parameter)

Comment: can u please give a example for time_point

Comment: Edited the answer to include both