# Store enum value in table

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt

I have a simple enum (or enum class, neither one is working )

```cpp
enum vote_option {
  upvote = 0,
  downvote
```

and a table which will store a value of that enum type.

```cpp
struct [[eosio::table]] poll
{
  uint64_t key;
  vote_option opt;

  uint64_t primary_key() const { return key; }
};
```

And the problem is the build is fine, but when I even `get table` I've got

```
Error 3015004: The type defined in the ABI is invalid
Error Details:
vote_option
```

Has anyone experienced this kind of problem ?

I use `eosio.cdt v 1.6.2` and `eosio  v1.8.4` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a custom type you must also define the type to a built in type. A list of accepted types by EOSIO can be found here, https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/1932/3333.

For instance, your custom enum is actually a **uint8_t** type.

You'll need something like ..

```
## header file

enum e_vote_option {
  upvote = 0,
  downvote
}

typedef uint8_t vote_option;

struct [[eosio::table]] poll
{
  uint64_t key;
  vote_option opt;

  uint64_t primary_key() const { return key; }
};
```

```
### source file

vote_table.emplace(_self, [&](auto& o) {
    o.key = vote_table.available_primary_key();
    o.opt = e_vote_option::downvote;
});
```

With this format, your ABI file will correctly set **vote_option** as **uint8_t**.

Comment: So, you agree that we can't use enum typed members in tables. The same goes for enum classes with underlying type specified.

Comment: I have personally used the suggestion I gave and it worked fine. I just had to declare the enum and then specify it's type to be picked up by the ABI.

Comment: What I can't understand is how do you declare the enum and then typedef the same name. You can't have enum and typdefed type at the same time.

Comment: Right so you have a name for the enum type. Then you typedef the uint8_t, and use the typedef name in place of the enum type. In the end, the enum is a declaration of a certain type of objects, in this case I used the uint8_t example. https://github.com/eostitan/delphioracle/blob/write-hash/include/delphioracle/delphioracle.hpp#L39 this example might give you more clarification

Comment: Thank you, fully understood ;)
Before marking your answer as accepted, could you please edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: Apologies for taking some time to get around to this. Please check the answer and see if it fits with more accuracy.